# POST Authorization trouble: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, authorization, basic-authentication

Sometimes when I run tests I am getting this error: 
`TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`, which is caused by this code:

```
params = {
  .....
}

auth_headers = {
  'Authorization': "Basic #{Base64.encode64('XXX:XXX')}"
}

post back_request_url, params: params, headers: auth_headers
```

`back_request_url` path is valid, same params. When the authorization fails, I am getting (as it should be) simply `401` - but, when the authorization passes - then this error happens.

This is something in rails - this action doesn't enter into action provided by `back_request_url`.

What it could be?
My version of rails is `5.1.3`

Comment: please provide complete server logs for this request

Comment: This is an test only, but I've already fixed this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **#FIXED**

**The issue** - Authorization parameters (name and password) has been set in the beginning of the test:

```
test 'failure no id' do
  MyGem.auth_name = 'xxx'
  MyGem.auth_pass = 'xxx'
  params = {
    ...
    ....
    (no id)
  }

  post back_request_url, params: params, headers: @auth_headers
  assert_response 400
end
```

And the action:

```
class BackRequestController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery except: [:new]
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: MyGem.auth_name, password: MyGem.auth_pass

...
```

And they wasn't sometimes set and refreshed, when the test has begun.

**Solution**

Simply :)

```
class BackRequestControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Engine.routes.url_helpers

  setup do
    MyGemauth_name = 'xxx'
    MyGem.auth_pass = 'xxx'
    @auth_headers = {
      'Authorization': "Basic #{Base64.encode64(MyGem.auth_name. + ':' + MyGem.auth_pass)}"
    }
  end

...
...
...
(TESTS)
```